# suggestion and ideas on how to create email notification system via php

Tags: php, joomla

i am building a small social networking and in every user profile page, should be a button that says "request contact details". if someone clicks on it, the owner of that profile receives an email that says:" user xyz asked your contact details".

i don't ask that someone finds me the solution, but can anybody give me a suggestion on how to  get closer to this solution? i am studying right now php but don't know when will be able to accomplish this task

any help appreciated

Comment: Are you just asking how to send mail in php? http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime (for mass mailing)

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with Joomla, I would assume you are using Joomla for your site. You will want to learn how to write Joomla MVC components -

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5

It would probably be helpful to know how to write modules and plugins as well -

module - http://www.minitek.gr/tutorials/joomla-16-tutorials/item/21-how-to-create-a-new-custom-module-in-joomla-16.html

Plugin - http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin

When you get to that point, you will be using the built in Joomla class JMail to send emails with Joomla - http://docs.joomla.org/JMail/1.6

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Joomla. You could just tap into Joomla's mail by doing something like this -- http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_send_email_from_components

or if you prefer to do something custom phpmailer is nice -- phpmailer.worxware.com